# Recursion to get the number of different combinations of n people and k groups

Tags: java, recursion, combinations

I'm practicing recursion using Java and I've hit a problem. I'm trying to make a method which I'm calling "groups" which takes a number of people and how many groups there are and returns the number of different combinations there are of people and groups. Also, the ordering of people in the groups does not matter, nor does the ordering of the groups.

The code I have so far is:

```
public long groups(int n, int k) {
    if(k==1) return 1;
    if(k==n) return 1;
    else return groups(n-1, k) + groups(n-1, k-1);
}
```

However it returns the wrong values. The first two lines are the base cases, which say if there is 1 group, then there is only one way to split the people up, makes sense. The other is when there are just as many people as there are groups, in which case theres only one way to split them up, one person into each group. The last statement is where I think I'm having problems, I would think that each time it does a recursive call, one person has to be taken out (n is the number of people, so n-1) and that person can ether join a group (k) or make their own group (k-1).

I'm just having a little trouble figuring out how recursion works and could use a little help.

These are the values I'm expecting:

```
groups(2,1) = 1
groups(2,2) = 1
groups(3,2) = 3
groups(4,2) = 7
groups(4,3) = 6
groups(5,3) = 25
```

Comment: Please can you give examples of expected and received answers?

Comment: missing handling of `n < k` (error or zero) and, just for completeness, you should check the input values, that is, `n` and `k` must be greater than zero

Comment: @mattbasta: ["The homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812) but, Adam, please follow the linked homework guidelines, including stating special restrictions, what you've tried so far, and what specific part of the problem is confusing you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is something missing in the implementation of that part

> ... and that person can ether join a group (k) ...

I think the person can join 'k' groups, so the code must be

```
    public long groups(int n, int k) {
        if(k==1) return 1;
        if(k==n) return 1;
        else return k * groups(n-1, k) + groups(n-1, k-1);
    }
```

(was missing multiplication by `k`)

Comment: Oh and I would give you a vote up, but apparently I can't until I have 15 reputation. Sorry! :(

Comment: no problems, I liked the algorithm to solve the assignment and thanks for accepting the answer (got some reputation for that)

Answer (score 0):

There's a much easier (faster) way to compute combinations -- that's the [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). While I can understand that your teacher may want you write a recursive function this way to become familiar with recursion, you can use this formula as a check.

In your case, you're reporting the wrong expected values here. What you want is

```
groups(2,1) = 2
groups(2,2) = 1
groups(3,2) = 3
groups(4,2) = 6
groups(4,3) = 4
groups(5,3) = 10
```

and the code you've posted is correct if the values above are what it's supposed to return.

(If not, perhaps you can better clarify the problem by explaining more clearly how the problem you're solving differs from the [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).)

Comment: Well my assignment says "Given n students, return how many ways you can divide them into k groups." And then gives the values above in my question.

Comment: Also, when I run the code above I get: "groups(2,1): 1
groups(2,2): 1
groups(3,2): 2
groups(4,2): 3
groups(4,3): 3
groups(5,4): 4
groups(5,3): 6" Which aren't the same as the values you gave.

Comment: @Adam: OK there was a little detail that I didn't notice until after I posted: To get the values I gave, the base case `if(k==1) return 1;` would have to change to `if(k==0) return 1`.